# No serializer found for class org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding

Tags: java, sql, jooq

As part of my spring boot application, I am auto-generating my DO classes using jooq. After getting this data from db as do object, I am trying to convert it to map using jackson library. But it is giving the error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 3):

As of jOOQ version 3.10, you cannot simply serialise / deserialise jOOQ `Record` types using Jackson without specifying your own custom bindings. Another option is to map the jOOQ `Record` into your own POJO ("DO") object first, e.g. using:

```
Result<Record> result = ctx.select(...).from(...).fetch();
List<MyPojo> list = result.into(MyPojo.class);
```

And then you should be able to easily serialise that list instead.

Comment: I got the same error when creating a `newRecord()`.

Comment: @Ibrahim.H: I'm not convinced that is the same error. This here is about Jackson, yours may be something entirely different. Can you please ask a new question?

Comment: I'll try to isolate the issue, coz it seems a little different with Ratpack and Groovy, inspired from https://danhyun.github.io/2016-gr8confeu-rapid-ratpack-groovy/